# Can't enable CORS globally in ASP.NET web API core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I configured the CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory like this

```cs
serviceCollection.AddMvc();
serviceCollection.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory(policyName));
});
```

But when I run the application received the issue:

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors.Internal.CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory'
> from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors, Version=6.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.'

I configured some dependencies like `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors` but I have received the same issue. Could you give me any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET Core 3.0, [some pubinternal APIs that includes `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors.Internal` are updated to be truly internal](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/4932), which seems cause this issue.

If you want to migrate older version ASP.NET CORE App to 3.0 or above version, and enable CORS, you can refer to [this doc about "Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware).